# HOW spliting image using OPENCV in python and convert nan by 0

Tags: python, opencv, nan, divide-by-zero

I have an image and want to split it into three RGB channel images using CV2 in python and do a division.

In my division : DIVISION= (G-R) / (G+R-B), I have nan values and, I would to convert nan by 0.

Any help please ?

```
> import cv2
> import numpy as np
> img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
> B,G,R = cv2.split(img)
> DIVISION = (G-R)/(G+R-B)
```

Comment: That won't be possible. You will have to add your denominator by 1. `DIVISION = (G-R)/(G+R-B+1)`

Comment: @JeruLuke since you're subtracting B, even adding 1 can result in a 0.

Comment: @Miki You are correct. We can take the denominator as a separate variable and find the maximum between the value and 1. `denominator = G+R-B`, `denominator = max(denominator , 1)`

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6db555d30115642fedae0cda05604874) says "For integer types when src2(I) is zero, dst(I) will also be zero."